# postgreSQL error initdb: command not found

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu

i was installing postgresql on ubuntu using linuxbrew:

```
brew install postgresql
```

it seems to work fine but after that because i was installing PostgreSQL for the first time i tried creating a database:

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8
```

but it returned as:

```
initdb: command not found
```

i tried running the command with `sudo but that doesn't helped`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

run `locate initdb` it should give you the list to chose. smth like:

```
MacBook-Air:~ vao$ locate initdb
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.3/bin/initdb
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.3/share/doc/postgresql/html/app-initdb.html
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.3/share/man/man1/initdb.1
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin/initdb
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/share/doc/postgresql/html/app-initdb.html
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/share/man/man1/initdb.1
/usr/local/bin/initdb
/usr/local/share/man/man1/initdb.1
```

So in my case I want to run

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.1/bin/initdb
```

If you don't have mlocate installed, either install it or use

```
sudo find / -name initdb
```

Answer (score 17):

There's a good answer to [a similar question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/513386/setting-up-postgresql-gives-error-sudo-initdb-command-not-found).

In short:

1. Postgres groups databases into "clusters", each of which is a named collection of databases sharing a configuration and data location, and running on a single server instance with its own TCP port.
2. If you only want a single instance of Postgres, the installation includes a cluster named "main", so you don't need to run `initdb` to create one.
3. If you do need multiple clusters, then the Postgres packages for Debian and Ubuntu provide a different command [`pg_createcluster`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html) to be used instead of `initdb`, with the latter not included in `PATH` so as to discourage end users from using it directly.

And if you're just trying to create a database, not a database cluster, use the [`createdb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/createdb.1.html) command instead.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and found the answer [here](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/postgres-formula/issues/160).

Ubuntu path is

> /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/initdb

Edit: Sorry, Ahmed asked about linuxbrew, I'm talking about Ubuntu.
      I Hope this answer helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue caused by the `brew install postgresql` not properly linking postgres. The solve for me was to run:

```
brew link --overwrite postgresql
```

Answer (score 1):

if you installed postgresql and got `initdb: command not found`

you should add below line in ~/.bashrc (OR .zshrc) file:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/x.y/bin/`

and then

`source ~/.bashrc`

Actually the initdb is exist in that path.
after that you can use initdb command.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the PATH to run from any location

```
sudo nano ~/.profile
```

inside nano go to the end and add the following

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/" ] ; then
    PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/:$PATH"
fi
```

and configure the alternative

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/initdb initdb /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/initdb 1
```