# Importing database in PostgreSQL using pg_dump having ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "psql"

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

i am using PostgreSQL database for my application. Now i have to import my all databases in it.

I am using this command for importing,

```
psql -U postgres Employees < dbimport.pgsql
```

but it is not importing. I have already created the database with name Employees in my PostgreSQL.
Getting Error like,

```
42601: syntax error at or near "psql"
```

Please suggest me if i am going wrong.

Comment: 42601: syntax error at or near "psql"

Comment: `psql` is a command line program, not a SQL command (and again: that error message should be part of your question, not a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have postgres client installed, probably you have misconfigured environmental variables ($PATH), to find the `psql` use instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44106963/5315974

Basically you need to use`mlocate` (if you have it installed) or just `find`...

Unrelated, but also I would avoid using mixed case in database name...

Also `42601: syntax error at or near "psql"` error code means you try to run `psql` as SQL statement, which it is not - look into your `dbimport.pgsql` if you have not SQL there - maybe it is shell (or some other) script?..

Answer (score 0):

The error `42601: syntax error at or near "psql"` is a syntax_error from the database not from the terminal, so the value of $PATH is not wrong.

It looks like the file 'dbimport.pgsql' which you are trying to import does not contain the importable data.

Can you confirm, how this backup was taken? Or the content of file 'dbimport.pgsql'.