# how do I solve the testing postgres package error

Tags: python, postgresql, testing, flask

I have tried all documentation resource on testing.postgres but I keep getting the same error.
The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Oloyede Emmanuel\Documents\Hook\tests.py", line 42, in setUp
with testing.postgresql.Postgresql() as postgresql:
File "C:\Users\Oloyede Emmanuel\Documents\Hook\env\lib\site-packages\testing\common\database.py", line 92, in init
self.initialize()
File "C:\Users\Oloyede Emmanuel\Documents\Hook\env\lib\site-packages\testing\postgresql.py", line 50, in initialize
self.initdb = find_program('initdb', ['bin'])
File "C:\Users\Oloyede Emmanuel\Documents\Hook\env\lib\site-packages\testing\postgresql.py", line 144, in find_program
raise RuntimeError("command not found: %s" % name)
RuntimeError: command not found: initdb
```

Comment: Either put the command on the `PATH` in effect or use an absolute path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [postgreSQL error initdb: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104241/postgresql-error-initdb-command-not-found)